# how to keep the facebook connection in another site

Tags: php, facebook

I am doing a website which allow user to invite their Facebook friends, may I know how to keep the connections between them and their friends automatically when their friends register as users in our site? For example, John, Jerry and Kay are friends in Facebook, and John are a member of abc.com, meanwhile, he'd also invited Jerry and Kay to join abc.com, Jerry join it but Kay hasn't. So in abc.com, John and Jerry are automatically friends. May I know what is the logic here? Thanks everyone if you guys willing to explain to me.

Comment: Google for Facebook oAuth, that should put you on a right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the facebook api to get user's friends.  Then cross reference that list with your members in your database.  I assume you are already using the facebook api from your question.  It is just a matter of storing and cross referencing the data.

If you dont need it to be truly interactive however, you can use the `facepile` [social plugin](http://developers.facebook.com/plugins) to simulate such a relationship.  it will show pictures of all user's friends that like the same object.

Comment: Thanks for reply @NappingRabbit, yeah I am thinking how to storing and cross referencing the data, do you know that?